# Is $c_2+a_2+b_2>a_1+b_1$ in this specific case?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

For positive real numbers, 
let $c_2+a_2>a_1$, $c_2+b_2>b_1$, $a_2+b_2>a_1$, $a_2+b_2>b_1$, $a_1>a_2$ and $b_1>b_2$. Under these conditions, can we claim that $c_2+a_2+b_2>a_1+b_1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_2=b_2=c_2=1$ , $a_1=b_1=2-e$ , $e$-is small number . As we can see $c_2+a_2>a_1$... but $c_2+a_2+b_2=3$,$a_1+b_1=4-2e$ .Take $e=\frac{1}{4} $ and you will see that your inequality is false .